# Accessing Swift Protocol in Objective C and then back on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm a new comer into Objective-C and swift and I need to make changes to an existing code base.

I have added a protocol defined in Swift

File **AController.swift**

```
@objc
protocol MyDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
  func saveTapped()
  func discardTapped()
}

@objc
class AController: UIViewController, BcAiDelegate {
  ...
}
```

The protocol is used as a member is **BController.h**
and the code compiles and builds w/o issues

```
// imports are placed here

// @class declarations are here
@protocol MyDelegate;

...

@property (nonatomic) MyDelegate* myDelegate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL myFlag;
```

And then I try to access this field in **CController.swift**

```
@objcMembers class CController: UIViewController {

...

func doSomething() {
   let bController = BController()

   // When I try to access `myDelegate` it isn't recognized as a member of the controller
   // I get an error message that says - Value of type 'BController' has no member 'myDelegate'
   bController.myDelegate = nil

   bController.myFlag = true // This lines works fine
}

...
}
```

If I look at the swift 5 interface generated from **BController.h** I can see the following definitions:

```
...
open var myDelegate: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!

open var myFlag: Int33
...
```

I tried created new initializers in **BController.h**, one that receives a **Bool** and the other that receives **MyDelegate** - and the behavior is the same, the one with **Bool** is accessible in **CController.swift** and the other isn't

*Obviously I'm missing some part - but what?*

Comment: You didn't show us the definition of BController so how are we supposed to know what the problem is? Personally I tend to believe the compiler.

Comment: `CCController.swift` is include `SWIFT_MODULE_NAME-Swift.h` ?

Comment: It should be `id<MyDelegate> myDeledate` for protocols

Comment: @Cy-4AH Thank you - `myDelegate` is now recognized in `CController`